# how to vps server backup local machine every month automatically(ubuntu)

Tags: mysql, backup, ubuntu-16.04

I have a VPS Server with Ubuntu 16.04 Server from vultr.com.

I want to backup its content to my local machine (Ubuntu 16.04), this task has to be repetead every month automatically (database and project files).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending where you want to back them up, a very simple approach could be:

1. `mysqldump` the database (it can be done while running)
2. Use `rsnapshot` to keep your project's directory in sync with the remote location.

Have you considered using a version control tool like `git` for the project? I'm assuming is a standard web development set-up.

Put all of the above in a script and put it in your `crontab`.

Comment: cron meaning? crontab?

Comment: @VJRanga yes. I'll update the answer.